# How to keep subtitle in HandBrakeCLI?

Tags: subtitles, handbrake

I do use the commandline version of HandBrake -  **HandBrakeCLI**.

---

I like the *Normal* preset of HandBrake and would like to continue using it. I found the actual command input of this preset, but what do I have to add / remove to keep subtitles?

```
 ./HandBrakeCLI -i DVD -o ~/Movies/movie.mp4 -e x264  -q 20.0 -a 1 -E faac -B 160 -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,dtshd,dts,mp3 --audio-fallback ffac3 -f mp4 --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset veryfast --h264-profile main --h264-level 4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Subtitles should be automatically removed unless you specify to keep them.

```
-s "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

should be generic enough in most cases to keep all subtitles (track 1-6), you can add as many numbers as you want, since requesting non-present subtitles causes no error.

There are more options, like "keep the language that was selected for audio".

https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide#SubtitleOptions

For you then it might be

```
./HandBrakeCLI -i DVD -o ~/Movies/movie.mp4 -e x264  -q 20.0 -a 1 -E faac -B 160 -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,dtshd,dts,mp3 --audio-fallback ffac3 -f mp4 --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset veryfast --h264-profile main --h264-level 4.0 -s "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

to keep all subs.

Comment: that link is broken.